# In the context of the Windows API, what extra information do the debugging symbols provide that the export table doesnt provide?

Tags: winapi, debugging-symbols

Take for example, 'kernel32.dll', the export table already provides the list of exported functions, then in what use case, would I need to download the debugging symbols for it from the MS symbol server?

Answer (score 2):

without symbols most of the calls would be like call dword ptr ds :[12345678]  or call 45678976  or jmp 86753535 etc

with symbols it would be like call dword ptr ds:[exitprocess]

call foo32!blah

jmp some-non-exported-address-that-was-named-by-symbol etc

apart from names symbols provide typeinfo

like push foo->blah

instead of push [eax+60]

also exported apis can be ordinal exports 
then all calls will look like call ord1 call ord2 call ordn
without a symbol file you will have a hard time renaming and analyzing them
take a look at mfcxx.dll

Answer (score 2):

Most available public symbol files provide only global function and variable names (both exported and **non-exported** ones). A small minority (e.g. ntdll, kernel32, ntoskrnl) also include various system **types** (structures , enumerations) which is very useful for low level debugging. But even without types you can often guess a lot just from the function names.